# Column is invalid in the select list when selecting count of children rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a parent table A(id,fld1,fld2), and child table B(id,parentId,fld1, fld2)

I want to select A.* and the count of the children rows

my query is:

```
SELECT A.*, COUNT(B.parentId)
INNER JOIN A ON B.parentId = A.id
GROUP BY B.parentId
```

but I'm getting:

> Column 'A.id' is invalid in the select list
>   because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the
>   GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's another way:

```
SELECT A.*, B.cnt
FROM A
CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt
             FROM B
             WHERE B.parentId = A.id
            ) As B
```

Answer (score 1):

Old fashion (correlated subquery):

```
SELECT A.*, (SELECT COUNT(*) As cnt
             FROM B
             B.parentId = A.id
            ) As cnt
FROM A
```